# How to get the hostname or entire url of the visitor website in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If the user clicks a link on http://facebook.com/my_path/ that points to http://example.com/ the value of `request.domain` will be example.com

But in my case, I would like to get the visitor's host name ***facebook.com*** and entire url ***http://facebook.com/my_path/***

How to get that? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's called "referer", look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Use request.referer, it is from a library called Rack, which Rails itself uses, more info here https://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Request/referer

Comment: request.referer returns a nil for me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting `debugger` in the controller and access that controller in your browser. When you reach the `byebug` shell, try to check the output of the `request` variable like below

```
(byebug) request
#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x007fe49c151840 @env={"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.errors"=>#<
```

the output should have your referrer path if it exists